# Is there a "Postmaster" (email / smtp) stack exchange?

Tags: discussion

I notice that sometimes there are pure SMTP-related / postmaster type questions posted here, but I'm wondering if there is a stack exchange devoted exclusively to all things email.  SMTP, spam /abuse handling, DMIK / SPF, etc.

If there isin't a postmaster.stackexchange.com - why not?  It's not like email is a fringe or seldom-used application after all.  There are many topics under the umbrella of SMTP / email (handling, server config, RFC, etc) that would be neatly handled if there was such a specific stack exchange forum.

Until there is, is this the default forum to post email-related questions?

Comment: "why not?" Because no one tried probably, and followed the rules, you have to prove it would get enough audience. And "There are many topics under the umbrella of SMTP / email (handling, server config, RFC, etc) " + "DKIM/SPF" might be also the problem as these subjects can be discussed on other sites: [sf] for server config for example... See https://area51.stackexchange.com/faq for all the details on creating a new SE site.

Comment: I don't think the number of questions related to email delivery is large enough to warrant its own Stack Exchange.  Its a pity that its not immediately obvious that webmaster questions are on topic on Webmasters.  [ Indeed, this caught me out early on when I started participating on Webmasters ]

Comment: Very related: [Are questions about email hosting on-topic?](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1451/are-questions-about-email-hosting-on-topic)

Comment: You could always try to start one at Area51, but I suspect it wouldn't get off the ground.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't currently anything quite like a "postmaster" Stack Exchange. However, there are several Stack Exchange sites that cover different email-related topics. Looking back in the history of Meta for precedent, I found this answer by John in 2016, which sounds reasonable to me:

[Are questions about email hosting on-topic?](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1453/54214)

Basically, depending on the nature of an email question, it should be on-topic on Webmasters, Super User, Server Fault, Web Applications, or Stack Overflow.

Going through your list, my opinion for on-topicness is:

- **SMTP:** Configuring a client goes on Super User ([example](https://superuser.com/q/1342090)), configuring a server goes on Server Fault ([example](https://serverfault.com/q/263546/297452)), configuring a software library (coding) goes on Stack Overflow ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/882712/2234742)).
- **Spam/abuse handling:** Goes on Server Fault ([example](https://serverfault.com/q/436327/297452)).
- **DKIM/SPF:** Anything DNS is generally on-topic here on Webmasters ([example](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/87220/54214)), but if it's specific to a server that you're hosting in a professional capacity, it might be a better fit for ServerFault ([example](https://serverfault.com/q/52830/297452)).